# "Agree" vs. "concur"

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between *agree* and *concur*? Which is the more common to use? For instance, someone said something to me and I want to say that he is right. Should I say *I agree with you* or *I concur with you*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*[Agree](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/agree?q=agree)* and *[concur](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/concur?q=concur)* mean the same thing in this context, but the latter is more formal. Both words may be used with or without *with*.

> I agree.
>
> I agree with you.
>
> I concur.
>
> I concur with you.

Comment: I agree with you that usually they mean pretty much the same thing.   However, _concur_ indicates that the speaker came to the same conclusion on their own beforehand, whereas _agree_ doesn't necessarily indicate that.

Comment: Could we maybe say "concur with" is only not suited to a direct response to the statement that is concurred with?

Comment: @JasperLoy Good point, it does not have to be 'before'.  More accurate would be to say that the conclusion was reached independently.

Comment: @TM - This seems to be how my brain reached for the word. During a recent debugging session my colleague posted his explanation, and I went with 'I concur' because my (separate) investigation had reached the same conclusion. If I'd just read his explanation and thought it sounded sensible I'd have 'agreed'.

Answer (score 9):

As @Jasper says, the words mean pretty much the same thing. I suppose *concur* could be a *little* bit more "formal" than *agree*, in that it's [not so well-known](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=16&gs_id=17&xhr=t&q=define+hyperbolic&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&newwindow=1&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=define+hyperboli&aq=0&aqi=g2g-s1g1&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b92501f416479a1e&biw=1237&bih=874). But that's really just because it's "dated". From [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concur%2Cconcur+with%2C+agree+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconcur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconcur%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagree%20with%3B%2Cc0):

[image: "Concur" is as popular as "agree" in 1800, but slopes downwards drastically, while "agree" stays about the same. "Concur with" is less popular.]

In answer to OP's specific question, *use* **agree** *unless you want to sound stilted / pretentious*. Whilst there's no grammatical reason why *with you* is any more "correct" after either verb, in terms of usage I suspect it may be omitted more often after *concur*. I suggest that purely because the brevity of *I [verb]* can carry "imperious" overtones, better suited to the more formal *concur*.

Comment: Nice plot. Where does that come from?

Comment: @Isaac it is a [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams).

Comment: @Isaac: Sorry - I keep forgetting to include a link when I show an NGram chart.

Answer (score 9):

I usually see:

> I agree with you.  (most common)
>
> I agree.  (also common)
>
> I concur.  (not so common)

To say *I concur with you.* is awkward, but I'm not sure if it's technically *wrong*.

Comment: I share your misgivings re *I concur with you*, but comparing [agree](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+agree%2CI+agree+with&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [concur](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+concur%2CI+concur+with&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it seems that although *concur* is less common overall, it's just as likely to be followed by *with*.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right.  M-W even lists it in their example:  2b : to express agreement <concur with an opinion>

Answer (score 7):

Reflecting on this, I think that *concur* describes a passive acquiescence, *agree* an active one. Imagine a meeting. The Chair says *Are we in favour of what is proposed?* This is followed by heads nodding wisely and a general murmuring suggesting that those present approve, that is, they 'go along with it', they **concur**.

Now imagine a different meeting. The Chair again says *Are we in favour of what is proposed?* One of those round the table says *This is a bold initiative and we should give it our support*.’ Another says *I did have some reservations, but I can now see the advantages and you can rely on my vote*. And so on. Individually and collectively, they **agree**.

Comment: @archer: There's the additional point that the syntactic role of the two verbs can vary. For example, 'We were all agreed' is a legitimate sentence, but 'We were all concurred' is not.

Comment: I think it's completely the reverse. One can "agree" with something without saying anything at all or expressing it in any way. An agreement can be completely passive. One cannot "concur" unless one expresses that agreement. If nobody says or does anything in response, the Chair may say "I'll just assume you all agree", but he cannot say "I'll assume you all concur", since they *didn't* concur.

Comment: Perhaps there’s a transatlantic difference, then. In the British government department in which I once worked, those consulted on a proposal would write 'I concur', if they had no objections. I always took that to be something rather less than wholehearted support. Much the same goes for the word 'consensus'.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Even if it's less than wholehearted support, concurring is more than simply agreeing. Agreeing can involve *no* action at all. Concurring requires one to actually do something.

Answer (score 4):

Concurring, I think, has the connotation that you are coming to agreement with a group consensus that is in the process of forming. In other words, the group is coalescing around a particular position, and you are helping that coalescence. Agreement is usually more directed towards a statement that someone else just made.

Comment: I concur (but Stack Exchange requires me to add these unnecessary words).

Answer (score 2):

It would be odd to say "I concur with you" because *concur*, coming from the Latin root *con* (together or with) and the verb *currere* (to run), is literally "run with". Accompaniment is implied.

Comment: "accompaniment" as in "being with someone"? I don't think so. It would indeed be odd to use "concur" in this context but only because of its formality, not because of a difference in meaning. When speaking we use "agree" more often.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that *concur* has a connotation that the speaker had already formed an opinion (before hearing the opinion of the other party), and that those two opinions are in agreement.

On the other hand, *agree* does not carry any such connotation.  In other words, the speaker may or may not have had an opinion before hearing the one that they are agreeing with.

Answer (score 1):

I agree.  I would only use *concur* in the sense of saying that two things concur: the meetings run concurrently, for example, or these number concur.  I personally would not say *I concur* for *I agree* unless I was using it ironically.

Answer (score 1):

To *concur* is to *express* agreement.

Although there's significant overlap and it's almost never wrong to use one instead of the other, there is a subtle difference. If you concur with someone, you *express* the same view they do. Agreeing can be just a state are in, one of holding the same view as someone else. Concurring is an act you perform, the act of expressing agreement with another's view.

While "agree" is certainly sometimes used to express the act of agreeing, "concur" is almost never used to express the state of agreement. For example, if a board of directors gets together and all of them think closing the company is best but they haven't discussed it yet, you could say: "Though they hadn't discussed it, they all agreed that closing the company would be best." But you would not say: "Though they hadn't yet discussed it, they concurred that the best option was to close the company." You can say "they would soon concur".