# Can I say "I concur with something" instead of "I agree with something"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Hi I'm still learning English and I rather have problems with grammar.

So my question is can I use

> I concur with this statement

instead of

> I agree with this statement

Is it weird? Does it sound unnatural?

Comment: Review the discussion [here][1]..................


  [1]: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47399/agree-vs-concur

Answer (score 2):

For the most part *agree* and *concur* are synonyms, although *concur* has other usages that are apart from the meaning of *agree*.  There *are* however some subtle differences, that arise, and only shows up in certain circumstances.

Let me give you an example:

> CEO: "You *will* agree to sign this letter of resignation or I will press charges."
>
> Chairman: "I concur!"
>
> Employee: "I do not agree."

The CEO cannot say, "You *will* concur to sign ..."

The chairman can also say "I agree", however he would come across as being a subordinate to CEO's directive, whereas he's actually ratifying it.

The employee, on the other hand, cannot really use the phrases *I concur* or *I do not concur* because they sounds odd in adverserial situation as a direct statement.

However, if the employee wanted to be dry about it he could say,

> "I do not concur! but I agree because I really don't like jail food"

I wonder if this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

The verb 'agree' is in much more common usage than the verb 'concur', so I would recommend the former though both are grammatical as the dictionary shows.

Comment: I appreciate to your help!!...