# Commutative versus non-commutative synonyms?

Tags: terminology, synonyms

Is there a term to distinguish between different kinds of synonyms?

I'm thinking of the contrast between the terms "borrowing" and loan word" (commutative) [raised [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393564/borrowing-versus-loan-word-is-there-a-difference)], where one item can directly replace the other in virtually all situations, as against "agree / concur" (non-commutative) where this isn't the case to the same degree, and where it's fairly easy to find situations where the two differ.  [Agree/Concur Link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47399/agree-vs-concur)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60520/discussion-on-question-by-robin-hamilton-commutative-versus-non-commutative-syno).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that while there isn't, in linguistics, a single term to distinguish between two kinds of synonyms, there are at least two sets of terms which discriminate between *degrees* of synonymy.  The exact issue I was concerned with can be found dealt with [COGNITIVE SYNONYMY: A GENERAL OVERVIEW](http://facta.junis.ni.ac.rs/lal/lal200902/lal200902-05.pdf).

There we find Cruse:

```
 The scale which [Cruse] has set up consists of absolute synonymy, cognitive    
 synonymy and near-synonymy.
```

And Lyons:

```
 The scale presented by Cruse is the most general. There also are other 
 views. Lyons (1981:148) claims that there are absolute synonymy, complete 
 synonymy, descriptive synonymy and near-synonymy.
```

What may be of relevance is that I came on this paper earlier tonight while exploring the question, "Is synonym a linguistic term?"

The answer to that, incidentally, would seem to be that while the term "synonym" occasionally crops up in linguistics texts, it is not *itself* a linguistic term --  *synonymy*, yes, *synonym* no.  It may be treated as a figure of speech in manuals of rhetoric, but I haven't been able to confirm this.